# how to stop JButton from changing position when a Jlabel is added before it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I have a JLabel (seriesInformationLabel) that is initially blank. There is a Jbutton (copyButton) next to it. Problem is everytime the JLabel loads a text value, the JButton moves to the right. How do I stop this JButton from moving?

```
private void init() {
    super.initializeLayout();
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Box buttonPanel = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));
    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
    copyButton = new JButton(Utilities.getString("COPY"));
    copyButton.setActionCommand(COPY);
    copyButton.setEnabled(false);

    seriesInformationLabel = new JLabel();
    seriesInformationLabel.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    seriesInformationLabel.setName(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_seriesInformationLabel");

    buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
    buttonPanel.add(seriesInformationLabel);
    buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    buttonPanel.add(copyButton);
    buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buttonPanel.add(seriesInformationLabel);
buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
buttonPanel.add(copyButton);
buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Well the free space changes as the text of the label changes.

This means that the space available for the "glue" will change equally between the two glue components causing the button to shift.

If you don't want the button to move then you need to get rid of the second "glue" component:

```
buttonPanel.add(seriesInformationLabel);
buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
buttonPanel.add(copyButton);
//buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Maybe instead add another rigid area if you don't want the button completely at the right edge of the panel.